# How to update one value in my userData using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update specific value in my user data.

User data can look like this :

```
User : {
    role : [0, 1],
    name : "x",
    CommonId : 'xxx',
    skills : [
        {
            id : 1,
            name : 'x',
            level : 'null'
        },
        {
            id : 2,
            name : 'x',
            level : 'good
        },
        .........
    ]
```

First, I have to access the specific user who want to make an update ($user) => (working)

Then, i need to access the skills data and found the one to update ($matchedSkill) => (working)

```
public function UpdateLevelSkill(Request $request)
{
    $level = $request->get('level');
    $commonId = $request->get('commonId');
    $userId =  $request->get('userId');

    $user = User::where('microsoftId', $userId)->first();
    $skills = $user->skills;

    $matchedSkill = (object) [];

    foreach ($skills as $skill) {
        if ($skill['CommonId'] === $commonId) {
            $matchedSkill = $skill;
            break;
        }
    };

    return response()->json($matchedSkill);
}
```

When I return `matchedSkill`, I got the object skills I want to update.
But then, if I add

```
$matchedSkill->Level = $level;
$user->save();
```

I got error:

> Attempt to read property "Level" on array"

even if `matchedSkill` is an array.

How can I update the skill ?

I have tried to use `['Level']` with no success

I have also tried to add condition `(if matchedSkill ...)`

Comment: _even if matchedSkill is an array._ Then the error is appropriate. Is `$matchedSkill` a model that you are updating its value using the `save` method?

Comment: Ups, I have put the wrong code (I am doing some test so), I saved "$user" not "matchedSkill" (just a minute, I edit the post )

Comment: In my code, matchedSkill is an object that I create. I thing maybe instead of creating a matchedSkill object, I can directly found the right skill in the ' foreach ($skills as $skill)' and make the user update here, what do you thing about it ? Or, i need to tell again that matchedSkill is $skill['CommonId'] === $commonId ?

Comment: _make the user update here_ : Yes, you may do so. I couldn't find any key `CommonId` in the skills array. Is it intentional to not show in the user object?

Comment: yes, I have a lot of value in userData but CommonId is here, and i find the user data with no prob' (i update the post to show CommonId)

Comment: You casted empty `matchedSkill` to object, then assigned an array value, so it now is array, not object

Comment: You're right, because if I change with   $matchedSkill['Level'] = $level; then I got error "Call to a member function save() on array". I will check on that and tried another way, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating with consideration that matchedSkill is an array (working):

```
public function UpdateLevelSkill(Request $request)
{
    $level = $request->get('level');
    $commonId = $request->get('commonId');
    $userId =  $request->get('userId');

    $user = User::where('microsoftId', $userId)->first();
    $skills = $user->skills;

    $matchedSkillIndex = null;

    foreach ($skills as $index => $skill) {
        if ($skill['CommonId'] === $commonId) {
            $matchedSkillIndex = $index;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($matchedSkillIndex !== null) {
        $matchedSkill = $skills[$matchedSkillIndex];
        $matchedSkill['Level'] = $level;
        $skills[$matchedSkillIndex] = $matchedSkill;
        
        $user->skills = $skills;
        $user->save();

        return response()->json($matchedSkill);
    }

    return response()->json('Skill not found.');
}
```

Comment: You can put body of the second `if` into first one, but don't forget to `break` loop